# Iterate in directory to backup sqlite tables in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite

I write a script to backup sqlite files in directory, but I am adding more database to directory and want to put in for loop the script but I stuck building the script as in example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
for fn in $DIR/*.db; do
echo $fn ".backup '$fn_$DATE.backup'"
done
```

when I run this code to check how I it works:

```
/db/buyuk_sozluk.db .backup '20190216.backup'
/db/doviz.db .backup '20190216.backup'
/db/football.db .backup '20190216.backup'
/kktc.db .backup '20190216.backup'
/db/ulkeler.db .backup '20190216.backup'
```

but I am expecting to get output like below:

```
/db/ulkeler.db .backup '/db/ulkeler.db_20190216.backup'
```

I am not able to ad file name before the date, I couldn't figure out why its working for first $fn but not for the second one. After I will manage to make it work, I will change the echo with sqlite3 command.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have a variable called `fn_`. Probably you were trying to use `fn`. Try with

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for fn in $DIR/*.db
do
    echo "${fn} .backup '${fn}_${DATE}.backup'"
done
```